# How to delete all objects for a given entity from the ManagedObjectContext

Tags: iphone, cocoa, cocoa-touch, core-data

I don't want to use the reset method for my ManagedObjectContext.  I only need to remove all of the objects for a specific entity, but I don't see any methods for doing this.  Selecting all of the objects for a specific entity and looping over each and deleting them works, but it's very slow.

Answer (score 7):

*Selecting all of the objects for a specific entity and looping over each and deleting them works*

That's pretty much how you do it.

Comment: That's it?  Ridiculous.  The reset method takes milliseconds versus this looping crap can take many seconds.

Comment: If your entities have dependency relationships with other entities, those have to be managed. I'm pretty sure that's why they are called managed objects. There can be some overhead from this.

Comment: I didn't mean any rudeness, just explaining why these objects are called "managed" — there's other stuff going on under the hood when you delete an object and save the context. If your deletions aren't running quickly, I'd recommend taking a look at the relationships in your data model, specifically looking at the delete rules for those relationships. If you "cascade" deletions, for example, there is overhead from these additional transactions. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Categories to the rescue! Again.

NSManagedObjectContext+MyExtensions.h

```
@interface NSManagedObjectContext (MyExtensions)

-(void) deleteAllInstancesOfEntity:(NSString*) entity;

@end
```

NSManagedObjectContext+MyExtensions.m

```
#import "NSManagedObjectContext+MyExtensions.h"


@implementation NSManagedObjectContext (MyExtensions)

-(void) deleteAllInstancesOfEntity:(NSString*) entity {
     NSError* error;

     for (NSManagedObject* o in
            [self executeFetchRequest:[NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:entity]
                                error:&error]) {
          [o.managedObjectContext deleteObject:o];
     }
}

@end
```

Usage

```
NSManagedObjectContext *myMOC = ...;
[myMOC deleteAllInstancesOfEntity:@"SmellyCheese"];
```

Categories are awesome.